# There is a big open pipe to the attic in my AC closet?

Tags: air-conditioning

[image: front of ac unit]
[image: hole into attic]

I have a pipe that lets air from the attic into my ac closet.  This closet also has the hot water heater.  However, both of these already have vent pipes that vent out through the ceiling.  Is there a reason this hole would be there?  Its not connected to anything so i wonder if its from an old unit?  House is 45 years old

Comment: Is the yellow flex line for natural gas, is it a combination a/c and heating unit?

Comment: Yes, it is heat and air.  It is natural gas for heating and water heater is gas too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possibly for makeup air. The units need air to burn effectively, since they are in a closet, there will not be enough air getting to them for effective combustion.